# Which android view should be used to display a jetbrains.letsPlot() + geomHistogram() -object?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, lets-plot

I am having some trouble including a Plot-object (produced by `jetbrains.letsPlot() + geomHistogram()`) within the `activity.xml` for a Kotlin Android app. I am familiar with basic activity elements but I don't know which one to use in this case and I can not figure it out using https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android' WebView to display a plot.

`jetbrains.letsPlot() + geomHistogram()` produces a Figure object.

First you will have to convert it to a simple Map object using `toSpec()` method:

```
        val spec = when (plot) {
            is Plot -> plot.toSpec()
            else -> (plot as GGBunch).toSpec()
        }
```

Next, you will generate a string (plot HTML representation) using `PlotHtmlHelper`:

```
val html = PlotHtmlHelper.getStaticDisplayHtmlForRawSpec(spec)
```

This way you can generate a web page and load it to WebView. The page should also contain a script tag for loading the Lets-Plot JS library.

The code could look similar to this (but with a newer library version - 2.2.1 currently): https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-kotlin/blob/master/demo/browser/src/main/kotlin/frontendContextDemo/BrowserDemoFrontendContext.kt

If you are using Kotlin/JS you may want to take a look at this example as well: https://github.com/alshan/lets-plot-mini-apps/blob/main/js-ir-frontend-app/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt

---

**Update (oct 17'23)**

Check out new [Lets-Plot Skia Frontend](https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-skia). You can now target Android in a Compose Multiplatform project.